# Do objects created from an Openshift template overwrite existing objects?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, openshift

I took a look at the Openshift documentation, but I couldn't find out what exactly happens when a template is processed and the objects defined in it created. More specifically: what happens to existing objects (created in a previous deployments)? Are they overwritten completely or edited/patched?

Comment: You get an error. The matching is based on <object type>/<name>, and if the object already exists, then the template creation just error's out on that object. If I recall, I think using `oc process` causes the entire process to stop when it hits first error, but using `oc new-app` with a template will process the whole thing, and only error-out on the ones that match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During *oc process* you just pass template's parameters (see [templates](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/templates.html#generating-a-list-of-objects)) and generate final list of objects. Then the list of objects can be passed to *oc create* or *apply*. *oc create* should be used to create new objects or returns 'already exists'. *oc apply* can create/update existing objects.

```
oc process -f <filename> | oc create -f -
```

In case of DeploymentConfig if you have [config change trigger](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/deployments/basic_deployment_operations.html#config-change-trigger) it will start deployment after *oc apply*